# Convert char to int in C?

Tags: c

I was reading some examples in how to convert char to int, and i have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch1 = 125, ch2 = 10;
    ch1 = ch1 + ch2;
    printf("%d\n", ch1);
    printf("%c\n", ch1 - ch2 - 4);
    return 0;
}
```

as i know that if we made any Character arithmetic the char type will convert to int

so why the result of  first printf statement is **-121**  not **135** as i know int range will handle 135 so no overflow will happened.

the second printf statement will print y because we put %c in the printf .

Comment: " any Character arithmetic the char type will convert to int" yes, but you store the result in a `char` type so you convert it back to char

Comment: `ch1 = ch1 + ch2;` if your compiler uses *signed* chars then it will very likely overflow here

Comment: @UnholySheep: There is no overflow. In `ch1 + ch2`, both operands are promoted to `int`, and the result fits in `int`. In the assignment, the right operand is converted to `char`. When the value does not fit during a conversion to a signed integer type, the result is not overflow, which would have undefined behavior, but an implementation-defined result or signal, per C 2018 6.3.1.3 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "char" variable types usually default to the "signed char" type.
The "signed char" variables have a range of values from -127 to +127.

Exceeding this positive range limit caused the negative result from this program.

The value of -121 is displayed because that is the two's compliment value of the bits set for the unsigned char value of 135.

Comment: Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-defined and shouldn't be assumed to be "usual".

Comment: The "signed char" variables have a range of values from -128 (not - 127) to +127.

Comment: @johnH thank you, now i understand why the result is negative but why is -121 ? could you please explain this to me , thanks .

Comment: @LEarn123 - I expanded my answer to explain the -121 value display. Note that unsigned char have 8 value bits and no sign bit; however, the signed char has 7 value bits and one (1) sign bit. The two's compliment interpretation is more complicated for negative values than positive values.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by bolov, the result is a char type, so you are converting it back to char.

Explanation: Since the result of `ch1 + ch2` is stored in `ch1`, which is a char type, the calculation operation will max out at 127 and will continue, starting from the lowest char value of -128. So the resulting `ch1` will be -121:

```
ch1 =  -128 - 1 + (125 + 10 - 127)
or ch1 = -121
```

To resolve this, just store the result to an `int` variable or if you really want to optimize the memory, then to an `unsigned char` variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char ch1 = 125, ch2 = 10;
    unsigned char ch3;
    ch3 = ch1 + ch2;
    ch1 = ch1 + ch2;
    printf("%d\n", ch1);
    printf("%c\n", ch1 - ch2 - 4);
    printf("%d\n", ch3);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
-121
y
135
```

Comment: @curios, i dont understand your solution actually , why you put " -128 - 1 + (125 + 10 - 127) " from which rule in C you get this ? thanks

Comment: @LEarn123 you may verify it by assigning  `char ch = 128;`. Print result will be -128. Now let's calculate the way mentioned in my answer, i.e.  ch =  -128 - 1 + (128 - 127). = -128. Reason of this is mentioned in my answer.